# How to hide a workflow button based on user in openerp 7?

Tags: button, attributes, workflow, hide, odoo

Is there a way to hide a workflow button based on logged user?

I'm developping an OpenERP 7.0 Module and in a certain point of this process a user can take a the worflow of to his responsability.
I tried this `<button name="take_request" string="Take request" help="Take this request to your responsability" attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('state','!=','treatment'),('owner','=',user.id)]}" />` (like I would do in a domain rule), but I am getting the following error:

```
NameError: name 'user' is not defined
```

If I try `<button name="take_request" string="Take request" help="Take this request to your responsability" attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('state','!=','treatment'),('owner','=','user.id')]}" />` (whit user.id inside quotes) I get no error, but it isn't hiding the button.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly sorted out, and it's working fine. I used a field.function in my object a used this field in my button's invisible attibutes. I'll leave here the relevant code for future reference.

In my py, created a function that checks if I'm responsible for any of the requests and added a field.function on my object:

```
    def _check_ami_responsible(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
        """ Checks if user is responsible for this request
        @return: Dictionary of values
        """
        res = {}
        for req in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            if req.responsible_name.id == uid:
                res[req.id] = True
            else:
                res[req.id] = False
        return res

    (...)

   _columns={
        (....)
        'ami_responsible': fields.function(_check_ami_responsible, type="boolean", obj="generic.request", method=True),
    }
```

Then in my view I added condition ('ami_responsible', '=', False) on button to hide it when not responsible for that request.

```
<button name="confirm_request" class="oe_highlight" string="Confirm Request" type="workflow" attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('ami_responsible', '=', False), '|',('state','!=', 'submitted'), ('needs_reformulation', '=', True)]}" />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `uid` instead of `user.id`.In xml you cant pass 'user' which is a res.user object. But you can pass active_id, uid,parent. if it has parent view, context etc

Comment: Using uid (without quotes) I get the same "NameError: name 'uid' is not defined" and with quotes it doesn't filter wath I want.

Tryed to use domain as attribute of button but it didn't work either. Solved it using a field.function boolean (I'll leave the answer for other users with the same problem)